# How can I output a composite signal made of two signals with different time period at the same time on one audio channel in matlab code?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, composite, audio

```
%-------------------------------------------------------------------

% Function to Generate ECG of 1 heart beat signal

function [Heartbeat,t1] = ECG_Gen (HR,pulse_width,Amp)

Fs = 48000;

delay = ((60/HR)/2)-(0.5*pulse_width);

t1 = -delay:(1/Fs):delay;

Heartbeat = Amp*tripuls (t1,pulse_width);

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%Test Circuit configuration

function [FECG_MECG,Mixed_ECG,fastTime] = Test_Circuit (FHR,MHR)

Fs = 48000;
%FHR = 150;
%MHR = 60;
Fpulse_width = 30e-3;
Mpulse_width = 60e-3;
FAmp = 0.2;
MAmp = 0.5;

% Fetal ECG Gen
%------------------------------------------------

[FECG,FHR_Delay]= ECG_Gen (FHR,Fpulse_width,FAmp);

% Maternal ECG Gen
%------------------------------------------------

[MECG,MHR_Delay]= ECG_Gen (MHR,Mpulse_width,MAmp);

% Composite signal implementation
%------------------------------------------------

% Set parameters for Composite signal Algorithms

if length (MECG) > length (FECG)        % Check for time sequences for both ECG signal
    slowECG = FECG;                     % Set interpolation to slower rate
    fastECG = MECG;
    timeSeg = length(MECG);
    fastTime = MHR_Delay;               % Set sampling times
    slowTime = FHR_Delay;    
else 
    slowECG = MECG;
    fastECG = FECG;
    timeSeg = length(FECG);
    fastTime = FHR_Delay;              
    slowTime = MHR_Delay;
end

FECG_MECG = zeros (timeSeg,2);    % To hold stereo output

FECG_MECG(:,2) =  fastECG(1,:);        % Assign higher rate signal to one channel

% Interpolation on the slower rater sampled ECG

slowECGInterp = interp1 (slowTime,slowECG,fastTime);

slowECG = num2cell(slowECGInterp);          % Conversion to cell Array in order to remove NaN

slowECG(cellfun(@(slowECG) any(isnan(slowECG)),slowECG)) = [];

slowECG = cell2mat(slowECG);

j = 1;

for i = 1:timeSeg

    FECG_MECG(i,1) =  slowECG(1,j);   

     if j == length(slowECG)
         j = 0;
     end     

    j = j+1; 
end

Mixed_ECG  =  FECG_MECG(:,1) + FECG_MECG(:,2);      % to hold mono output






 %while (1)
  %sound(Mixed_ECG ,Fs);
%end

%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% Test Wave script

clear all
%clc
clc
Fs = 48000;

%for i = 1:3
%toc

MHR = 60;
FHR = 200;

% Obtain ECG interpolated signal and composite
[FECG_MECG,Mixed_ECG,fastTime] = Test_Circuit (FHR,MHR);

% for test purposes
[MECG,MHR_Delay]= ECG_Gen (60,60e-3,0.5);

%t = timer ('TimerFcn','stat=false','Period',2.0);
wavwrite (FECG_MECG(:,2),Fs,'ECGwav.wav');
i = 0;
a = 1;
tic
while (1)

while (toc < 20*a)

sound (MECG,Fs);

end
toc
a = a+1;
[MECG,MHR_Delay]= ECG_Gen (60*a,60e-3,0.5);

if a > 4
    break
end

end

%start(t)
%tic
%t = cputime;

%y = wavread('ECGwav.wav');


%while (1)
%    sound(y,Fs);
%end
%toc
```

Hey Thank you very much for getting back to me, I have made use of your interpolation but still have minor problems from the reading obtained from the Monitor. Fist of all, say I have a constant signal with fixed time period say, 0.8s and I want to add composite signal of say 0.3s, I have managed to use your interpolation method to sample the 0.3s signal at the rate of my 0.8s signal. I think I have solved this issue. Second issue deals with how to combine the two signals which I have managed to do somehow but when I use a while loop in order to repeat the composite signal say over 20s, the signals obtained from the sound output isn't quite what I expected since its sounding the array of stored composite signal which contain ( signal with 0.8s = slowInterp signal of 0.3s ). I have include all the codes and functions. Basically, I need the sound output in while loop to sync with the composite signal for example: if I have a signal that repeats every 1s, I would expect to hear a beep in a while loop that runs for 10s to produce 10 beeps, etc

Comment: I'm really not sure how to help, you are clear in what you would like to get, however there is so much code, it's missing the `ECG_Gen` function, it's hard to tell where to start.  It looks like they are on the same step, but there are so many unknowns it's hard to tell.

Comment: I have re posted the question with additional code and comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell exactly what you need, but probably doing interpolation on the sequence that is sampled at the slower rate would work for your application.

If `t1s` are your times from your faster sequence, and `t2s` are times from your slower sequence, and `slow` is your slower sequence then do:

```
slowInterp = interp1(t2s, slow, t1s);
```

now you will have the sequency `slow` sampled at the faster rate.

This is only useful for displaying the time series.  If you are doing any spectral analysis, this will introduce artifacts, but that is a more advanced topic.

Using the `resample` function in the signal processing toolbox could also be useful.

Comment: Hey Thank you very much for getting back to me, I have made use of your interpolation but still have minor problems from the reading obtained from the Monitor. I have re posted the question with all the codes and comments